# CMAKE file(COPY <src> <dest>) not alaways working

Tags: c++, cmake, build

So I am having a problem when calling the command:

```
file( COPY ${src_dir} DESTINATION ${dest_dir} )
```

Half the time it works, and then half the time I get an error:

> file COPY cannot set permissions on "${dest_dir}/subdir"

My issue is I have changed no permissions or touched these files in between execution. I would prefer to use this method to copy our files, as the other methods with `add_custom_command/target` does not seem to work on our side. I need to copy these files before our executable target is ultimately declared.

I would even be open to use a bash shell to do this copy command, but it has to be done at this specific point of cmake execution.

I have been wondering if `file (COPY...)` throws a return value, and if there is a way to possibly rerun the copy command if I get a return. Does anybody know if that is possible?

Can anybody give any help if they have run into this problem?

Thank you!

Edit:
I have already tried using different FILE_PERMISSIONS to see if it would function.

Comment: What host system? If your OS is hanging on to files (e.g. for indexing, or from the IDE) then some OS'es prevent changes to those files.

Comment: This is on Linux RedHat 7

Comment: maybe you need to call your make with sudo then

Comment: Unfortunately sudo is not an option due to the nature of where I work, so I have to deal with regular permissions.

Comment: `file(COPY)` afaik results in a fatal error on a failure; You may be able to use `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ...)` though which does allow you to check the results of the operation and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You might set permissions explicitly, with `PERMISSIONS <permissions>`, `FILE_PERMISSIONS <permissions>` and `DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS <permissions>`, or skip setting-of-permissions through `NO_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS`.

You could hack in a `ls -laR ${dest_dir}` command to see if there's anything special going on in the filesystem at the time `file(COPY ...)` is invoked.

Comment: I have actually tried this before, forgot to mention. When I look at the file system it says I have file permissions to all of the directories and files, thats why I am confused as to why it is locking me out.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing is simply using this copy step in a while loop, because it usually works the 2'nd time, if not the first. Not an elegant way, and may only apply to my case, but please leave other answers if somebody can think of other methods.